# script to open web browser and enter data

Tags: python

I am not sure if this is possible, but I was wondering if it would be possible to write a script or program that would automatically open up my web browser, go to a certain site, fill out information, and click "send"? And if so, where would I even begin? Here's a more detailed overview of what I need:

- Open browser
- Go to website
- Fill out a series of forms
- Click OK
- Fill out more forms
- Click OK

Thank you all in advance.

Comment: You would better do that using POST/ajax requests without the browser.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a number of tools out there for this purpose.  For example, Selenium, which even has a package on PyPI with Python bindings for it, will do the job.

Answer (score 0):

maybe you can use [zope.testbrowser](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/zope.testbrowser) it's really easy to use.